# Using Green's Function for a B.V.P - Why do I obtain two different particular solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $x''(t) - x(t) = e^{t}$ according to the boundary conditions $x(0) - x(1) = 0$, and $x'(0) - x'(1) = 0$, $t \in [0,1]$, using green's function.

Clearly $u_{1} = e^{t}$ and $u_{2} = e^{-t}$ are solutions to the corresponding homogenous equation.

I know that $u_{p}(t) =- u_{1}(t) \int  \frac{u_{2}(t)f(t)}{W(t)}dt + u_{2}(t) \int \frac{u_{1}(t)f(t)}{W(t)}dz$

But using Green's function,

$ u_{p}(t) = -u_{1}(t) \int_{t_0}^{t} \frac{u_{2}(z)f(z)}{W(z)}dz + u_{2}(t) \int \frac{u_{1}(z)f(z)}{W(z)}dz = \int_{t_0}^{t}G(t,z)f(z)dz$ where $G(t,z) = \frac{u_{1}(z)u_{2}(t) - u_{2}(z)u_{1}(t)}{W(t)}$.

I let $t_0 = 0$. Computing $u_p$ using $G(t,z)$ I get $\frac{e^t}{-4} + \frac{e^{-t}}{-4} + \frac{e^{t}t}{2}$, but finding $u_{p}$ without using the definite integrals, i.e, $u_{p}(t) =- u_{1}(t) \int  \frac{u_{2}(t)f(t)}{W(t)}dt + u_{2}(t) \int \frac{u_{1}(t)f(t)}{W(t)}dz$, I get $\frac{e^{t}t}{2} - \frac{e^{t}}{4}$.

I should get the same solutions. What is wrong?

Some of my work: Using green's function -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsvJH.jpg and using indefinate integrals instead https://i.stack.imgur.com/oau9e.jpg

**edit: ** Upon further examination of my homogenous equation solutions, *clearly* I am not very bright

Comment: Are the boundary conditions written correctly? Yes, I have confirmed they are written in my post as they are in the exercise. Though, my question deals with only the particular solution. I have no yet need to deal with the B.C.'s yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Green function, $y(t)=G(s,t)$ has to solve $L(y)=\delta(t-s)$ along with the homogeneous boundary conditions.

This is achieved by a construction 
$$
G(s,t)=C(s)·x_1(s\sqcap t)·x_2(s\sqcup t)
\qquad\begin{cases}s\sqcap t&=\min(s,t)\\s\sqcup t&=\max(s,t)\end{cases}
$$
where $L(x_1)=0=L(x_2)$ and $C(s)=1/(W(x_1,x_2)(s)$, where $W$ is the Wronskian 
$$W(x_1,x_2)(s)=x_1(s)·x_2'(s)-x_1'(s)·x_2(s).$$

---

With $L(y)=y''-y$  possible choices for the solution basis are,

- without regard to any boundary condition, $$x_1(t)=e^{t},\; x_2(t)=e^{1-t}$$ with Wronskian and Green function
  $$
  W(s)=e^s·-e^{1-s}-e^s·e^{1-s}=-2e
  \\~\\
  G(s,t)=-\frac12· e^{s⊓t}·e^{-(s⊔t)}
  $$
- or for zero value boundary conditions $x(0)=0=x(1)$:
  $$x_1(t)=\sinh(t),\; x_2(t)=\sinh(1-t)$$ with Wronskian and Green function
  $$
  W(s)=\sinh(s)·-\cosh(1-s)-\cosh(s)·\sinh(1-s)=-\sinh(1)
  \\~\\
  G(s,t)=-\frac{\sinh(s⊓t)·\sinh(1-(s⊔t))}{\sinh(1)}
  $$

---

Now let's try to satisfy the given boundary conditions for $y(t)$. The first reduces to
$$
y(0)=C(s)·x_2(s)·x_1(0)=y(1)=C(s)·x_1(s)·x_2(1)
$$
and the second
$$
y'(0)=C(s)·x_2(s)·x_1'(0)=y'(1)=C(s)·x_1(s)·x_2'(1)
$$
This however implies that $x_2(s)=\Bigl(x_2(1)/x_1(0)\Bigr)·x_1(s)$ which is independent of and thus valid for all $s$, so that $x_2$ is a multiple of $x_1$ violating the assumed linear independence.

There is no Green function for the given boundary conditions. Thus the Green function formalism using any Green function disregarding the specific boundary conditions will give a particular solution but provides no useful insights relative to the more elementary solution methods of finding a particular solution by undetermined coefficients or variation of constants.

Comment: I've not seen the Green's function defined like that before, but I suppose it is equivalent to the integral definition. Thank you for the answer.